# Elastic APM Server returns interleaved 503 and 202 responses on ES Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, server, apm

I have setup two Elastic APM servers which sends data to Elastic-search.

When I setup Elastic-search with single instance, Elastic APM server working fine responding 202 response.

When I setup Elastic-search cluster(3 master, 3 data nodes, 2 ingest, 2 coordinate nodes) , APM server server misbehaves responding interleaved 202 and 503
Using coordinate host in Elastic APM.

This link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/master/common-problems.html#queue-full  has some info but I am unable to resolve issue.

**Edited:**
Problem is one of Elastic APM server is not able to push data on ES cluster due to index. But I am still don't know why index name is different on single ES node vs Cluster